# In Rails, is there an easier way to search and replace query string parameter values?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4, search, replace, query-string

I’m using Rails 4.2.4.  IS there an easy way to replace query parameter values in a string that is my URL?  I want to replace the values represented by the search parameters “search%5Bstart_date%5D” and “search%5Bend_date%5D” so I tried this

```
url.sub( %r{search\%5Bstart_date\%5D=[^&]+}, "search%5Bstart_date%5D=#{new_start_search_date_str}" )
   .sub( %r{search\%5Bend_date\%5D=[^&]+}, "search%5Bend_date%5D=#{new_end_search_date_str}" )
```

but its not working.  My url is the same after I execute the above code (I verified the replacement strings are non-empty).  What is a foolproof way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it was indeed a typ-o.  I edited the question to show the correct code I had.

Answer (score 0):

You should use in-place-replacement `sub!` instead of `sub`

Comment: huh?  You mean change all my "sub" statements to "sub!"?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The `sub` method return new String. That's why your `url` is not changed